# Decoding JSON web response

Tags: json, swift, urlsession

I am trying to decode a simple JSON string, but the value for "age" below isn't coming through to my views.

Essentially the Steak object will be a specific steak and contain information that doesn't change (i.e. which guest ordered it and what type of cut it is). 
The Detail object will contain information that does change about the steak (i.e. how long it has been in the freezer)

Here is my code, any idea what I'm doing wrong? Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide that would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

URL setup

```
import UIKit

class NetworkManager: NSObject {

    struct Key {
        static let networkKey: String = "key"
    }

    struct APIURL {

        static func detailRequest(guest: String) -> String {

            return "https://website=\(guest)&token=\(NetworkManager.Key.networkKey)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
        }
    }

}
```

Steak object (i.e. Mike's steak)

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Steak: ObservableObject{

    var guest: String

    @Published var detail: [Detail]?

    init() {
        self.guest = "Mike"
        self.detail = nil
        self.getDetail()
    }


    private func getDetail() {
        DetailManager.getDetail(for: self) { (detail) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.detail = detail
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class SteakStore: ObservableObject {

    @Published var steaks: [Steak] = [Steak()]

}
```

Here's the struct containing the detail on the steak

```
import Foundation

struct Detail: Codable {

    var age: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case age = "age"

    }

}
```

```
import SwiftUI

extension Detail {

    struct List<T: Codable & Identifiable>: Codable {

        var list: [T]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

            case list = "data"

        }

    }

}
```

JSON Decoding function

```
import Foundation

class DetailManager {

    static func getDetail(for steak: Steak, _ completion: @escaping (_ detail: [Detail]?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: NetworkManager.APIURL.detailRequest(guest: steak.guest)) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970

                let detailObject = try decoder.decode([Detail].self, from: data)
                completion(detailObject)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

}
```

Which produces a JSON output such as this

```
[
   {
      "guest": "Mike",
      "cut": "filet mignon",
      "age": 8.00
   }
]
```

I then pull into a view such as this. My issue is that the age of 8.00 doesn't come through, but rather the default 0.0

```
import SwiftUI

struct SteakRow : View {

    @ObservedObject var steak: Steak

    var body: some View {
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                Text(steak.guest)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Text("\(steak.detail?.age ?? 0.0)")

                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.title)
                }
            }
            .padding([.trailing, .top, .bottom])
    }

}
```

Comment: The JSON format returns the array of the detail, but you decode with a single detail in your Steak. Otherwise, you don't need to separate the Steak and SteakStore and just use the one-call SteakStore and hold the array of the detail. 

In your decode line should be `let details = try decoder.decode([Detail].self, from: data)`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately that didn't seem to work. I tried changing everywhere it said Detail to [Detail] but got stuck on this error "Value of type '[Detail]' has no member 'age'". Any other suggestions/ corrections?

Comment: What did you change? Can you share here?

Comment: I have edited the code on here to show what I currently have. In the DetailManager and Steak classes I changed Detail to [Detail]

Comment: I'm getting the error in the SteakRow struct on this line Text("\(steak.detail?.age ?? 0.0)")

Comment: Oh!!! `Steak` is holding the list of detail so you can not call `steak.detail?.age`. You should call specific detail from `steak.detail` list.

Comment: Apologies - how would I do that exactly?

Comment: `SteakRow` will display information for the `Detail` so you don't need to pass the whole `Steak` to there